# Converting a flat array to a specific array format

Tags: php, arrays, nested, adjacency-matrix

Fellow PHP programmers, consider the following DB result:

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+
| node_id | parent_id | path          | branch |
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+
|       1 |         0 | /1/           |   NULL |
|       2 |         1 | /1/2/         |   NULL |
|       3 |         2 | /1/2/3/       |      1 |
|       4 |         3 | /1/2/3/4/     |      1 |
|       8 |         4 | /1/2/3/4/8/   |      1 |
|       9 |         8 | /1/2/3/4/8/9/ |      1 |
|       7 |         4 | /1/2/3/4/7/   |      0 |
|       5 |         2 | /1/2/5/       |      0 |
|       6 |         5 | /1/2/5/6/     |      0 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+
```

How does one get the following PHP array:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'parentId' => 0,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'parentId' => 1,
        'nodes' => [
            [ // when branch == 0
                [
                    'id' => 5,
                    'parentId' => 2
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 6,
                    'parentId' => 5
                ],
            ],
            [ // when branch == 1
                [
                    'id' => 3,
                    'parentId' => 2
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 4,
                    'parentId' => 3,
                    'nodes' => [
                        [ // when branch == 0
                            [
                                'id' => 7,
                                'parentId' => 4
                            ],
                        ],
                        [ // when branch == 1
                            [
                                'id' => 8,
                                'parentId' => 4
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 9,
                                'parentId' => 8
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The function should work with unlimited depth.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been hitting a wall.

Comment: Show us the wall, please (By wall I mean what you've tried xD)...

Comment: My attempt consisted of doing one pass indexing by id and then a second pass figuring out where to place a node that has a branch. It would work only with one level of recursion and was very similar to what you can see here: http://blog.tekerson.com/2009/03/03/converting-a-flat-array-with-parent-ids-to-a-nested-tree/. I unfortunately deleted it out of frustration ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function buildTree($arr, $parentID)
{
    $children = [];
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] == $parentID) {
            array_push($children, [
                'id'       => $item['node_id'],
                'parentId' => $item['parent_id'],
                'nodes'    => buildTree($arr, $item['node_id'])
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $children;
}

$tree = buildTree($flat, null);
```

UPD:

```
function getBranches($arr, $parentID)
{
    $branches = array();

    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] == $parentID) {

            $bKey = $item['branch'];
            $node = array(
                'id'       => $item['node_id'],
                'parentId' => $item['parent_id']
            );

            $firstNodeChild = false;
            if ($nodeChildren = getBranches($arr, $item['node_id'])) {
                $hasKey = array_key_exists($bKey, $nodeChildren);
                if ($hasKey && $nodeChildren[$bKey]) {
                    if (sizeof($nodeChildren[$bKey]) == 1) {
                        $firstNodeChild = $nodeChildren[$bKey][0];
                        unset($nodeChildren[$bKey]);
                    }
                }
                if ($nodeChildren) {
                    $node['nodes'] = $nodeChildren;
                }
            }
            if (!array_key_exists($bKey, $branches)) {
                $branches[$bKey] = array();
            }
            $branches[$bKey][] = $node;
            if (false !== $firstNodeChild) {
                $branches[$bKey][] = $firstNodeChild;
            }

        }
    }
    ksort($branches);

    return $branches;
}

$tree = getBranches($arr, 0);
```

Comment: This is actually close but the returned array does not have the expected layout. In your attempt, each node is inserted in the "nodes" attribute of the previous one. This is the behavior we want went a child has branches. If a node is a direct descendant of another without a branch attribute it should be a sibling but not a children (if that makes sense).

Comment: You don't want create 'nodes' key when children is not exists?

Comment: No. Your result start with `[0 => [id=>1, nodes=>[[id=>2, nodes=>[...]]]] ` when the expected result should start with `[0 => [id=>1], 1=>[id=>2, nodes=>[...]]]`

Comment: You id=>2 have parent id=>1 (DB result) and my tree result is right. You can check (seeing) it with generating <ul><li> nested list

Comment: I have tried your code and the resulting array doesn't match the expected output of the question. Your result: https://gist.github.com/mfauveau/821d04f3348add917919, expected result: https://gist.github.com/mfauveau/b2296fdd5fb04f1bfdb7.

Comment: It was pretty close but still does not provide expected result in my tests. For example when you add nodes that are not branching out (meaning having more nodes like 1 and 2 at the beginning of the tree) your code will still make them branch out. Thanks for trying tho!

Comment: @Matt hmmm... I not full understand your question? Maybe, because my English is bad. But for your data from gist -- my code is complete. You can try modified my code for final version. And your question interesting for me. Please notify me when you solve problem!